# NextEPC + OpemIMS = kernel for LTE node with VoLTE capabilities?

Tags: lte

I am trying to setup LTE kernel with VoLTE capabilities (test zone with mnc 001 and mcc 01).
But something goes wrong...
My Alcatel 5033d does not recognised that LTE node has VoLTE capabilities and never ask about P-CSCP address
There are too much ways to check and investigate.
May be somebody pass this way and could advice me?
Now I have in my configuration two machines with NextEPC and OpenIMS with FHoSS HSS.
I am successfully attach to LTE node with modem or smartphone and could access to the internet, but cannot make voice call.
My test SIM card has an ISIM profile but never use it.

I have checked my Alcatel - it could attach and VoLTE with SIM card from my local operator.

Comment: 2 posts
Thanks Meter: 0
 
More
May be I am wrong? Please advice me right place for this question!

Comment: Can you kindly add the logs that you captured while you face the issue and the version of software used.